# Using TextFree with a Google Voice account that uses Google Apps account

Tags: iphone, 3rd-party, gmail, google-apps

Is there any way to get TextFree working with a Google Voice account belonging to a Google Apps account?

I have been able to get it working with a Gmail account by simply adding the `user@textfree.us` address to the forwarding text message option in Google Voice. The problem with a Google Apps account is that it doesn't let you add additional email addresses to that list.

It won't let me forward to the phone number that TextFree gave me, since I must verify the phone with audio (as opposed to a text message), and TextFree doesn't let me answer phone calls.

Is there any other way to get the three services to work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by waiting to be invited to the TextFree beta which has voice. It will allow you to accept voice calls, which is what is required by Google Voice to verify a phone number.